# Initializing LSTM States Before the Prediction of a Day

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I would like to use an `LSTM` to predict a daily time series that is strongly dependent on the season. As test data, days from different seasons are used. Before the prediction for the test data takes place, I want to initialize the `LSTM` states with the training data of the previous day.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, input_shape=(sequence_size, inputs), return_sequences=True)
model.add(Dense(units=2)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

for _ in range(100):
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1, validation_data=None, shuffle=True)
    for day in range(num_test_days):
        #TODO: initialize state of LSTM with the training data of previous day
        y_pred = model.predict(X_test[day].reshape(1, sequence_size, inputs), batch_size=1)
```

As marked with `#Todo` in the source code, I would like to prepare the `LSTM` for the prediction of the day so that the state is adapted for predicting the test day. Is there a way?

Comment: if your data is strongly seasonal, I suggest making it stationary for better results. Also for the `fit` method you'd better turn off shuffling `shuffle = False` to keep the sequence of the time series. Otherwise you'll mess up time

Comment: is `model.reset_states()` what you're looking for?